# Arabic RSS can't be read in java it gives me symbols

Tags: java, rss

I'm trying to read `RSS` feed from a `URL` in java  but I don't get Arabic output just bunch of symbols, below is a sample code, it works with English but does not with Arabic... 
I tried couple of examples from web and could not solve it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            URL cali = new URL(
                    "http://services.explorecalifornia.org/rss/tours.php");
            URL aljazera = new URL(
                    "http://www.aljazeera.net/aljazeerarss/3c66e3fb-a5e0-4790-91be-ddb05ec17198/4e9f594a-03af-4696-ab98-880c58cd6718");
            InputStream stream = aljazera.openStream();
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while (true) {
                int data = buf.read();

                if (data == -1) {
                    break;
                } else {

                    sb.append((char) data);

                }

            }

            System.out.println(sb);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the Arabic language pack installed on your machine?

Comment: Well yes I can write in other programs... like microsfot word and etc... and I run this in eclipse... when alone I do Sysout and put static arabic text it works fine... but when reading this URL is not working... infact any RTL is not working I tried with other RTL languages

Comment: You probably need to convert the String encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify the encoding type of the `InputStream`:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (true)
    {
        int data = isr.read();

        if (data == -1) {
            break;
        } else {

            sb.append((char) data);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks your solution also worked and also I found different one as well that works fine... thanks for the time:

 BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myblog.openStream(), "UTF-8"));